# Using aggregate and lookup with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a User schema that has a key called associatedTeams.
It looks like this:

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  associatedTeams: [AssociatedTeamSchema],
});
```

Meanwhile, the associatedTeam schema looks like this:

```
export const AssociatedTeamSchema = new Schema({
  teamId: { type: ObjectId, required: true }, // each id will be a Team document
  userIsAdmin: { type: Boolean, required: true },
});
```

Finally, the Team Schema looks like this:

```
const TeamSchema = new Schema(
    players: [
      {
        type: ObjectId, // each will be a User
      },
    ],
);
```

How can I write an operation to remove a deleted user from all of their associated teams?
Right now I'm just trying to access all of the relevant teams. I'm fairly sure I can do it with the aggregate syntax, but I'm not sure of exactly how.

Perhaps something like this:

```
const teams = await UserInfo.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
      from: Team.collection.name,
      local_field: "associatedTeams.teamId",
      foreign_field: "_id",
      as: "teams",
    },
  });
```

I would really appreciate any help with this. The problem is I don't know how to reference the 'teamId' field in each associatedTeam. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use two `$lookup` first get data of `AssociatedTeam` and from that get `team`

```
const teams = await UserInfo.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: Team.collection.name, // AssociatedTeamCollection
      local_field: "associatedTeams",
      foreign_field: "_id",
      as: "associatedTeams",
    },
  },
    $lookup: {
      from: Team.collection.name, // teamCollection
      local_field: "associatedTeams.teamId",
      foreign_field: "_id",
      as: "team",
    },
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. Is there some way to use an updateMany operation on the Team model to achieve what I want?

Comment: could you update your question add sample data of each schema and your output expected data ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I came to. Hope this helps someone:

```
const UserInfo = mongoose.model("UserInfo") as IUserModel;
  const Team = mongoose.model("Team");

  // in each of the user's associated teams, I want to remove the user from
  // that team's players
 
  // for some weird reason I couldn't access the user document with 'this'

  const user = await UserInfo.findById(this._id);
  const ids = user.associatedTeams.map((team) => team.teamId);

  await Team.updateMany(
    { _id: { $in: ids } },
    { $pull: { players: this._id, admins: this._id } }
  );

  next();
```